# How to retrieve and list the first element of a field use Elasticsearch query (two compare and find end deleted duplicated documents in same index)?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

in my elasticsearch index all logs have a field called RES and the structure look like this :

```
Number:"12131", amount:8, referenceNumber:"140102129728883", expire:"1365", securityControl:0
```

I want to compare number in all indexed documents and delete duplicated documents.
can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you use the Number field as an _id? that would promise that this number won't be duplicated

Comment: Use aggregation, size 1 to get list of duplicated id, then call delete on them (store them cliens side so, wont be easy to do it in a one shot).